# How can I unify these two formulas in the destination table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a source table with tens of columns and tens of thousands of rows. I have a destination table with half a dozen rows. I want to count how many people are on a project *and only that project*. People (personal IDs) are listed multiple times for each project they are on, for unrelated (and necessary) reasons.

Currently in the source table, I have:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF((([Personal ID]=[@[Personal ID]])*([@[project name]]<>[project name])),[Personal ID]),[Personal ID])>0))
```

This creates the *any other project* field, which is 0 if they are only on this project and 1 if they are also on other projects.

The formula in the destination table is:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF((SourceTable[Any other project]=0)*([@[project name]]=SourceTable[project name]),SourceTable[Personal ID]),SourceTable[Personal ID])>0))
```

The problem is that the source table has tens of thousands of rows; the first formula is slow and is being calculated unnecessarily thousands of times over - it only needs to be calculated once per personal ID. It also recalculates every time I sort the table differently. How can I fold it into the formula on the destination table?

I thought about putting a helper column in the dest. table and using textjoin to give me a list of all the personal ids for each project in one cell per row. However, the IDs are repeated so many times that some of the projects throw #value! because the result exceeds excel's character limit within a cell.

Answer (score 1):

I worked out a way to do what I need:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(sourcetable[personal id],sourcetable[personal ID])>0))-SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(([@[project name]]<>SourceTable[project name]),SourceTable[Personal ID]),SourceTable[Personal ID])>0))
```

This takes all of the personal IDs, and subtracts all the people who are working on projects other than the one on this row in the destination table.

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of unique or distinct values in a range of cells (named "data" in the example below), you can use a formula based on the COUNTIF and SUMPRODUCT functions.

How the formula works
Working from the inside out, COUNTIF looks inside the data range and counts the number of times that each individual value appears in data. The result is an array of numbers that might look something like this: {3;3;3;2;2;3;3;3;2;2}.

After COUNTIF is finished the results are used as a divisor with 1 as the numerator. Values that appear in data once appear in the array as 1, but values that appear multiple times will appear as fractional values that correspond to the multiple. (i.e. a value that appears 5 times in data will generate 5 items in the array with a value of 1/5 = .2).

Finally, the SUMPRODUCT function sums all values in the array and returns the result.

Handling blank cells
If data might contain blank cells, you need to adjust the formula as follows:

=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(data,data&""))
The data&"" expression prevents zeros from ending up in the array created by COUNTIF when there are blank cells in data. It does this by ensuring that the criteria for an empty cell is "", and not zero. This is important, because a zero in the divisor will throw a #DIV/0 error. So this version of the formula won't throw an error when there are blank cells, but it will include blank cells in the count. If you want to exclude blank cells in the count, use:

=SUMPRODUCT((data<>"")/COUNTIF(data,data&""))
Slow Performance?
This is a cool and elegant formula, but it calculates much more slowly than formulas that use FREQUENCY to count unique values. For larger data sets, you may want to switch to a formula based on the FREQUENCY function. Here's a formula for numeric values, and one for text values.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't meet the conditions I need. I know how to search for a unique value, what I need is to check that a value exists next to a different value to the one it exists next to in this row.